# Copy and paste row in to a different workbook and then delete row

Tags: excel

I have a macro which copies row 4, pastes in to a different tab and then deletes the original row which shifts the data up so the next line can be processed. The workbook currently has 17000 rows of data which is then duplicated by the copy and paste, so is beginning to slow down drastically.

I have tried creating a macro which links the paste to another workbook, but doesn't seem to work properly as I am using a SharePoint version of excel which seems to stop the link, it is saving to a personal document rather than updating the shared file. Appreciate any help